# Barplot with diverging colors

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar

I'm trying to make a Barplot with diverging colors, for low, medium and high values.

My dataset is the average height of men for selected countries, and my code looks like the following:

```
d %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = reorder(Entity, as.numeric(Height)),
             y = as.numeric(Height))) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  coord_flip() + 
  theme_clean() +
  theme(legend.position = "none",
        plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) +
  labs(y = "Height in cm",
       x = "",
       title = "Average Human Height of Men for Selected Countries, 1980",
       caption = "Our World in Data") +
  geom_text(aes(label = Height),
            col = "black",
            size = 2.5,
            hjust = 1.1) +
  scale_fill_gradient2(low = "red", mid = "yellow", high = "green", aesthetics = "fill")
```

But for some reason, all the bars remain gray, as of the same color.

Str(d) gives me

```
'data.frame':   50 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ Entity                                       : chr  "Armenia" "Austria" "Azerbaijan" "Belarus" ...
 $ Code                                         : chr  "ARM" "AUT" "AZE" "BLR" ...
 $ Year                                         : int  1980 1980 1980 1980 1980 1980 1980 1980 1980 1980 ...
 $ Human.Height..University.of.Tuebingen..2015..: num  172 179 172 176 172 ...
 $ Height                                       : num  172 179 172 176 172 ...
```

The plot looks like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oZ3Ce.png)

Any ideas why this is happening?
Obviously, I want a plot with diverging colors, from green in the highest values, through yellow in the mid values, to red in the lower values.
Thanks in advance

Comment: If you want to have colored bars you have to map a variable on the `fill` aesthetic. Try with `ggplot(aes(..., fill = Height))`.

Comment: Yep, I've tried. But all the bars turned green. No divergency.  I actually found a solution, changing scale_fill_gradient2 to just scale_fill_gradient (no 2), without the mid value, and it works. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Great. The issue with scale_fill_gradient2 is that by default the midpoint is set to 0, which does not make sense in your case. But could set it via `midpoint = ...`.

Comment: Ok, ok. I'll try it out later. Thank you very much.